# Android User interface and the custom progressbar

Tags: android-progressbar

Hello I am a beginner in android programming Im facing a lot of issues since I had to learn everything by myself . I want to design a progress bar like this one

[image]

but I don't know where to start.

My question is how to crate a progress bar like this one and which code to implement in xml and java